# How to reduce docker storage usage

Tags: docker

`du -hc` on /var/lib/docker returns *16G*

`docker system df` returns *1.9G*

And that is *after* `docker system prune -a`

and

```
find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name “*.log” -delete
```

Or checking each containerID for suspicious size

```
docker exec -it <containerID> "/bin/sh"
du -h
```

Comment: Docker images are by default stored in /var/lib/docker, do you have images that would be using lots of your space?

Comment: Indeed. `du d1 -h /var/lib/docker/containers/ | sort -h` reveals a container bearing a 10G .log file

Answer (score 2):

Understanding your issue is from excessive logging, lets look at this:

> By default, Docker uses the json-file log driver and saves those logs in the overlay folder.

You can actually set limits on your docker logs like so:

**For running in the CLI, add this option (example of 10m)**

```
--log-opt max-size=10m
```

**For running from a compose file**

```
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        max-size: 10m
```

You can also set these limits globally in your daemon settings:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#configure-the-logging-driver-for-a-container

Comment: Thank you. Alas I can't confirm it's due to excessive logging. `ncdu` shows >16GB in /var/lib/docker/overlay